# Android resetting game clock to original time

Tags: android, android-activity, reset

I am trying to reset my game time to original time when the game is reset:
I am using a runnable to keep track of the time as shown:

```
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        if(!resetbool)
        {
            gametime = SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis();
            timeInMilliseconds = startTime - gametime;
        }
        else
        {
            resettime = SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis() - gametime;
            timeInMilliseconds = (startTime);
            reset = true;
        }
        //if(flag)
        //{
            //gamerestart = 0;
            //startTime = 60000;
            //flag = false;
        //}
        //timeInMilliseconds = startTime - gametime;
        //updatedTime = timeSwapBuff - timeInMilliseconds;
        int secs = (int) (timeInMilliseconds / 1000);
        int mins = (int) (timeInMilliseconds / 60000);
        secs = secs % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (timeInMilliseconds % 1000);
        if( (secs <= 0) && (mins <= 0) && (milliseconds <= 0) )
        {
            timerValue.setText("" + 0 + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", 0) + ":"
                    + String.format("%01d", 0));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Game Over",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
        }
        else
        {
            timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", milliseconds));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }
        if( (secs <= 10) && (mins <= 0) && (milliseconds <= 0) )
        {
            timerValue.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }
};
```

The else is meant to track time differently based on if the game is reset.  The problems are:
1) I have an activity I used to reset as:

```
if(startButton.getText().equals("Restart"))
          {
            flag = true;
            //if(reset)
            //{
            //  gametime = resettime;
            //}
            customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
            Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
          }
```

but when this code is executed the game is reset as I want but the resetbool will not be updated and the timer is not being reset to the original time.  Everything else reset as I expected and the OnCreate created everything just as I expected.  Is there a way to reset the systemclock or a way to have the timer be reset to original value when startActivity() executes?  Thanks for the help this has been stumping me for quite some time now.

Comment: Could you format the question appropriately?

Comment: Sorry, I had some trouble with the formatting